# PHP Logonhours format

Tags: php, binary, ldap, byte, pack

I'm trying to set logonhours for ldap users using php. I've gotten to the point where I've created a GUI that looks like active directories with blue and grey cells representing allowed and denied logon hours. My problem is intermittently I receive "Server unwilling to perform" and I think it has something to do with my **pack("C", bindec(strrev($chunk)))** nested in a foreach loop that isn't spitting out the correct format. Is there something I should tack on to the **pack("C", bindec(strrev($chunk)))** statement to ensure it's always in the right format for my DC to accept it?

```
if (isset($_POST['logonhours'])){
$set_logonhours = $_POST['logonhours'];
$set_logonhours_end = mb_substr($set_logonhours, -5); // EST TIMEZONE
$set_logonhours_begin = mb_substr($set_logonhours, 0, -5); // EST TIMEZONE
$set_logonhours_tz = $set_logonhours_end . $set_logonhours_begin; 

$set_eighthourchunks = str_split($set_logonhours_tz, 8);


foreach ($set_eighthourchunks as $chunk){
$logondec = pack("C", bindec(strrev($chunk))); //inconsistently works sometimes
}
echo $logondec;
$adldap->user()->modify($_POST['username'], array("logonhours"=>$logondec));


echo '<br>';
echo ldap_error($adldap->getLdapConnection()) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few months I decided to revisit this taking a different approach and figured it out by passing arguments to a powershell script!

PHP:    --REPLACE FOREACH IN QUESTION WITH FOREACH BELOW AND ADD WSHELL Object/Command

```
foreach ($set_eighthourchunks as $chunk){
// $logondec .= pack("c", bindec(strrev($chunk))); GETS THE ROW CORRECT BUT CANT CHANGE TOUCHING ROWS
$logondec .= bindec(strrev($chunk)) . ",";
}
$logondec = substr($logondec, 0, -1);

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Run('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adLDAP\\acctmgmt\\runaslogonhours.ps1 "DOMAINNAMEHERE\\' . ADMINUSERNAME . '" "'  . ADMINPASSWORD . '" '  .  $user . ' "' . $logondec . '"' );
```

POWERSHELL: --CREATE A PS1 SCRIPT IN THE SAME DIRECTORY CALLED runaslogonhours.ps1 WITH CONTENT BELOW

```
if (-not (Get-Module ActiveDirectory)){            
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory            
}

$PASSWORD = $args[1] #password for cred with rights to set logon hours
$USERNAME = $args[0] #username with rights to set logonhours

$CMD = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\adLDAP\acctmgmt\logonhours.ps1"
$user = $args[2] #user you want to set logon hours for
$inputhours = $args[3] #logon hours
$arrhours = $inputhours.ToString().Replace("'","").Split(",")
[byte[]]$hours= @($arrhours)
$replaceHashTable = New-Object HashTable
$replaceHashTable.Add("logonHours", $hours)
$ARGS = @($user, $hours) 

$pw = convertto-securestring $PASSWORD -asplaintext –force
$credential = new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential -argumentlist $USERNAME,$pw



Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace $replaceHashTable -Credential $credential
```